# Does syncing a telegram account with a phone with no contacts (recently reset to factory defaults) delete contacts from server?

Tags: contacts, sync, data-transfer, telegram

I am installing telegram on a new android device (sony xperia v, 4.3); The phone is reset to factory defaults with no contacts on it. If I sync the contacts with telegram account what happens? Does it transfer contacts FROM TELEGRAM SERVER and saves them TO THE PHONE? or stupidly does a one-way transfer FROM PHONE TO SERVER and DESTROY everything??

Its very important, because if it wont work I'll lose my only source of saved contacts(telegram server).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have all your telegram contacts in the telegram app wherever you login.